# Upgrade Worker / Idle Game

Tags: javascript

iam really new to coding and so i tried to code a little Idle game.

So my code for buying a worker is like:

```
function getGold(number){
  gold = gold + number;
  document.getElementById('gold').innerHTML = gold;
};

function buyMiner(){
  var costMiner = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,miner));
  if(food >= costMiner){
        miner = miner + 1;
        food = food - costMiner;
        document.getElementById("miner").innerHTML = miner;
        document.getElementById("food").innerHTML = food;

setInterval(function () {
  getGold(miner);
}, 1000);
```

so i´d like to know how to upgrade the worker, a miner in my code, to produce, for example, 3 gold instead of 1.

was thinking about a function that gets activated as soon as you buy the upgrade, but i dunno how to do this..

hope someone can help me..
thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your `getGold()` function, you pass the number of miners and add that number to gold, indicating that each miner collects 1 gold. Perhaps this might illustrate how to solve your problem better:

```
setInterval(function () {
  getGold(miner * 1);
}, 1000);
```

Basically, you want to multiply the number of miners by the amount per miner to get the amount generated. Or, put it in your `getGold()` function:

```
function getGold(miners, goldPerMiner){
  gold += miners * goldPerMiner
  document.getElementById('gold').innerHTML = gold;
};
```

Some syntax tips, while I'm here:

- You don't have to use `a = a + b`, a short, and generally clearer method is `a += b`. I used that in my function. Likewise, you can use `-=`, `*=`, `/=` for subtraction, multiplication, and division respectively
- It's fine now, but it's generally not good practice to put all your variables in global scope, it can lead to naming conflicts, which can be hard to debug

Comment: @Diliskar did it go well?